# django 2.0 form render

Tags: python, django, forms, render

I heve a problem w/ django rendering forms.
In a project im using django 2.0.5 and python 3.6.4

When i want to render simple form which just heve to take url but for some reason it dose not appear on a final web page

```
<form action="/videoConverter/" method="get">
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Here is form.py file
    from django import forms

```
class videoUrlExtract(forms.Form):
    video_info = forms.CharField(label='Video URL:', max_length=200)
```

I think problem in the diference of django from tuturial and django which i use

```
Def index(request):
    return render(request, 'homePage.html')
```

[tutorial](https://djbook.ru/ch07s02.html) 
it in russian but u can read code

sorry for my spelling

Comment: are you returning the `form` in your view function ? 
also you need to put `{{ csrf_token }}`

Comment: You need to show your view. There is no way we can help with the information you have given.

Comment: Without seeing the view, I'm guessing you're not passing the form into the context of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just forgot to add the form to the context:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'homePage.html', {'form': videoUrlExtract()})
```